# __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function (after Angular Upgrade 14 -> 15)

Tags: angular, webpack

I upgraded from Angular 13 to 15.1
The step to Angular 14 was successful and everything worked fine. But after upgrading to 15 I'm facing a problem.

When building I see:

> Warning: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in
> which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

And after trying to load the UI I see this in the dev console:

> **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function

This refers to a line like this (there are about 20 of them):

```
const importScripts = ctx => ctx.keys().forEach(ctx);
importScripts(require.context('../src/xyz', true, SCRIPT_PATTERN));
```

And `SCRIPT_PATTERN` resolves to this:

```
`/^.*\\/${foo}${bar}\\/.*${baz}\\.${ext}$/`
```

I read a lot about wrong imports (src imports from angular) or that you should use literals.

But I'm using a regex literal and I have no faulty angular imports.

I also tried putting the resolved regex directly as regex literal like this:

```
importScripts(require.context('../src/xyz', true, /^.*\/(controller|directive)\.(js|ts)$/)
```

But that didn't help.

We are using AngularJS and Angular in a hybrid mode and we also use the `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`

webpack@5.75

Going back to webpack@5.72 that we used with Angular 13 doesn't make a difference. So it must be something with Angular 15 that doesn't work anymore with our webpack config?